# security patches

Tags: security, patches, ce-1.8.1.0

I have received some alerts regarding security patches. So can someone guide me on whether to install the security patches or not to install them or what else to do about these security patches?

Comment: Hi You can test your install by visiting https://shoplift.byte.nl/

Comment: Ok I have done this by typing in website in the left square and /melbourne in the right square the answer I got was ERROR oops, I could not test www.decadentdaylilies.com could not connect. Does not exist? Perhaps you made a typo. Christine

Comment: Would suggest that you run the patches - they are important.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your website is VULNERABLE to the bug at https://shoplift.byte.nl.

if you are site is not safe then follow the steps.

Magento provides users with patches which may contain fixes for certain issues and/or add new functionality to a particular version of Magento.The reminder sent to all developers and merchants of the store to update this patches (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533).This 2 patches (SUPEE-5344 and SUPEE-1533) are available at the https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ .  try downloading this two patches from here.

For Installing this 2 patches you need SSH requirment.but some of the hosting providers wont allow the ssh access.

It is still possible to install this 2 patches without the help of the SSH.You can do it with the PHP also.

just download this 2 files from the https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/ .When i downloaded the 2 files names was as follows

1) Patch SUPEE-5344 :- PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh

2) Patch SUPEE-1533 :- PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh

This Both patch is for the Magento 1.9.0.1. you can get patch file for other magento version also you just need to select the magento version and download respective patch files.

Now just upload this 2 files to the magento root directory through the ftp and create a php file called applypatch.php with the following contents

1) for the first patch 5344

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

and run this file through browser http://www.yourdomain.com/applypatch.php

you will see the following output in the browser

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully…

Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

2) for the second patch 1533

```
<?php
print("<PRE>");
passthru("/bin/bash PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-18-32.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

and run this file through browser http://www.yourdomain.com/applypatch.php

you will see the following output in the browser

Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully…

Patch was applied/reverted successfully.

Patch has been applied successfully.to check patch has applied or not visit https://shoplift.byte.nl and provide their your domain name and the admin path and Test.

you will see “SAFE – good, http://www.yourdomain.com seems safe! Tweet this happy news”

Now you can see the list of core files which has been updated by this 2 patches in the file called applied.patches.list at app/etc/

Comment: Ok I typed in www.decadentdaylilies.com in the left square and     /melbourne in the right square  the answer I got was ERROR oops, I could not test www.decadentdaylilies.com could not connect. Does not exist? Perhaps you made a typo.

Comment: What happens now?